# Alternating Generator

Tags: python, generator, yield, iterable

My professor wants us to write a generator that takes *args as an argument, and yields the 1st value of the 1st argument, then the 1st value of the 2nd, and then the 1st of the 3rd. And when that's done it yields the 2nd value of the 1st, the 2nd value of the 2nd, etc.

I'm having a bit of trouble iterating through the iterables because they're of different lengths. So while one iterable may have a length of 4, the other might have a length of 2, and so trying to yield the 3rd value of both results in an error.

I want the generator to stop the moment it runs into an argument that has run out of values to iterate over.

Edit: This is what I have so far ...

```
temp = list(args)
while True:
    for x in range(len(temp)):
        for letters in args:
            yield next(letters)
```

Right now it gives me a **Type Error: 'str' object is not an iterator** When I try running this line ...

```
[print(i) for i in alternate('abcde', 'fg', 'hijk')]
```

I'm not allowed to use **zip** or any other imports.

**The function can accept strings and iterables as a parameter**

Comment: "I'm not allowed to use zip or any other imports." `zip()` is a built-in, not an import. Is it still forbidden?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up solving the problem (without the use of zip since I wasn't allowed to).

```
temp = [iter(arg) for arg in args]
while True:
    for x in range(len(temp)):
        for letters in temp:
            yield next(letters)
```

I used list comprehension to create a list of all the arguments while appending all of them as iterables. Afterwards, I simply used a while loop to while iterating through every value in the list repeatedly until I ran out of iterations. Once it detected that there was no more to iterate from, it broke out of the loop.

Comment: O now I see you were posting a question so you could answer it ... well +1 from me this is a pretty elegant solution ... although you really should just iterate over temp instead of its indices `for t in temp:for letters in t:...`

Comment: It needs adaptation...If you provide no arguments it will enter an infinite loop

Answer (score 1):

You could use a combination of `izip` and `chain` from [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html):

```
from itertools import izip, chain

def foo(*iters):
    return chain.from_iterable(izip(*iters))

for bar in foo([1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7]):
    print bar
```

Result:

```
1
3
6
2
4
7
```

In this example `izip(*iters)` will return an iterator that generates:

```
(1, 3, 6)
(2, 4, 7)
```

Value `5` will not be generated since `izip` stops when an individual iterator has been exhausted. `chain.from_iterable` will consider each tuple as an iterator of numbers and it will chain all these values together.

**EDIT**

Since `zip` is not allowed, we can provide our own implementation which is based on code provided from [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) page:

```
def foo(*iters):
    iterators = map(iter, iters)
    while iterators:
        for v in map(next, iterators):
            yield v
```

Comment: excellent answer :) you win ... unfortunately this is gonna break his head ... (and `izip_longest` may be more appropriate ... .combined with `filter(None,...)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately I can't use zip in my solution.

Comment: @Xari why not? zip is how you should do this /// (and I retract my earlier statement about izip longest now that I re-read the OP)

Comment: My professor wanted me to solve it without using zip.

Comment: Next time, mention those requirements in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Xari, you don't really need the outer for loop, e.g `for x in range(len(temp)):`

```py
def alternate2(*args):
    if len(args) == 0:
        return
    temp = [iter(arg) for arg in args]
    while True:
        for letters in temp:
            yield next(letters)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `zip()`:

```
>>> def mygen(*args):
...     for i in zip(*args):
...             for j in i:
...                     yield j
...
>>> a = mygen('abcde', 'fg', 'hijk')
>>> next(a)
'a'
>>> next(a)
'f'
>>> next(a)
'h'
>>> next(a)
'b'
>>> next(a)
'g'
>>> next(a)
'i'
>>> next(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a recursive solution

```
def myGen(x):
   for i in x:
       if len(i) < 1:
          break
       yield i[0]
   else:
      for j in myGen([z[1:] for z in x]):
          yield j
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def alternate(*args):
    shortest = min(map(len, args))
    for i in xrange(shortest):
        for arg in args:
            yield arg[i]

for i in alternate('abcde', 'fg', 'hijk'):
    print i
```

Output:

```
a
f
h
b
g
i
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to interleave generators but end all of then, not just until the shortest one. So I used:

```
def alternate(*args):
    """ Convert list of iterators into one iterator by interleaving. """
    list_iters = [iter(x) for x in args]
    while True:
        if len(list_iters) != 0:
            try:
                for it in list_iters:
                    yield next(it)
            except StopIteration:
                list_iters.remove(it)
        else:
            break
```